# check if css class exist and if yes how many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'd like to know if a style `class` exists and if yes, how many elements have it.

To know if a style `class` exists, I use:

```
if ($("*").hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
    alert("class exist : "+nb_checked);
}
```

But to know how many elements have the class, I can't figure out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a simpler approach:

```
$('.ui-state-active').length
```

Answer (score 4):

Just do:

```
$('.ui-state-active').length
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if($('.ui-state-active').length){
     alert("class exist : "+$('.ui-state-active').length);
}
```

Doc here :

http://api.jquery.com/length/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for both

```
c = $('.ui-state-active').length;
if (c>0) {
    console.log('There is '+c+' elements having required class');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you can directly [select all elements](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) which have a certain class. The syntax for this is the same as that for CSS selectors:

```
$(".className")
```

This creates a [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/), which is a collection of the matched elements. There are many useful properties of this object, one of which is [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/), the number of elements in the collection.

In your case, finding the number of required elements is as trivial as

```
$(".ui-state-active").length
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do both in one go:

```
var elements = $('.ui-state-active');
if(elements.length === 0) {
    alert('No elements with class ui-state-active!')
} else {
    alert(elements.length +  ' elements with class ui-state-active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$(".ui-state-active").length;
```